# Proof Verification: Equivalent Definition for Locally Compact Hausdorff Space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

The main theorem is as follows. I think most people are familiar with that:

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Then $X$ is locally compact if and only if for every $x\in X$ and every open set $U$ containing $x$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that ${\rm Cl}(V)$ is compact and ${\rm Cl}(V)\subseteq U$.

One direction is trivial, so we only need to show that the condition holds if $X$ is locally compact.

In my definition:

> **Definition.** A topological space $X$ is locally compact if for every $x\in X$, there is a compact subset $C$ of $X$ such that $x\in{\rm Int}(C)$.

I know there are many proofs available to that theorem, but **I wonder if I can prove it without referring to the one-point compactification**. Here follows my proof, which uses the regularity of locally compact Hausdorff space.

> **Proof.** Suppose $X$ is locally compact. For each $x\in X$, let $C$ be a compact subset of $X$ with $x\in{\rm Int}(C)$. For every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, since $X$ is regular, there exists a neighborhood $V'$ of $x$ such that ${\rm Cl}(V')\subseteq U$. Then we set
> \begin{equation*}
>     V=V'\cap{\rm Int}(C). 
> \end{equation*}
> Apparently, $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ where
> \begin{equation*}
>     {\rm Cl}(V)={\rm Cl}(V'\cap{\rm Int}(C))\subseteq{\rm Cl}(V')\cap{\rm Cl}({\rm Int}(C))\subseteq{\rm Cl}(V')\cap C. 
> \end{equation*}
> On the one hand, we have ${\rm Cl}(V)\subseteq{\rm Cl}(V')\subseteq U$. On the other hand, since ${\rm Cl}(V)$ is closed in $C$ and $C$ is compact, we can see that ${\rm Cl}(V)$ is also compact, as desired.

If anyone finds it interesting, could you please help me check whether my proof is valid? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is $X$ regular? You don't show it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have already shown (in my note) that every locally compact Hausdorff (LCH) space is completely regular, so I treat it as a fact known to us. In addition, the proof of that does not need this theorem at all.

Comment: You should explicitly mention that $\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(C)) \subseteq C$ uses that $C$ is closed (from $X$ being Hausdorff ). Otherwise it looks OK, if you choose the longer route of first showing $X$ to be regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better not to rely on $X$ being (completely) regular (which is also most easily proved by using the one-point compactification) but by using the classic fact that a compact Hausdorff space is normal (and hence regular).

So if $x \in O \subseteq C$ with $O$ open and $C$ compact (as the assumption of local compactness gives us) and $U$ is any open set containing $x$, then $U \cap O$ is open in $C$ which is (as said) regular and so we find an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ (open in $C$, so of the form $V=V' \cap C$ for some $V'$ open in $X$) such that $\operatorname{cl}_C(V) \subseteq U\cap O$ and then check that $V' \cap O$ is as required.